# Can we be allowed to choose a suitable forum if DBA.SE is not suitable?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I recently voted to close this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104679/sep-file-exclusions-symantec). I wanted to specify that it was off-topic and that it belonged on another StackExchange site (in this case, Information Security). However, I was only allowed the choice of StackOverflow or meta.dba.stackexchange.

Should we not be allowed to specify a group if neither of the default options is suitable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should flag the question as in need of moderator intervention.

[Moderators are able to migrate suitable questions to any destination.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86932/194636)

The *belongs on another site* close/flag shortcut exists for **common** destinations where migrating users on the source site are likely to be **familiar** with the on-topic rules for the proposed destination (no one wants to migrate rubbish or off topic questions).

I doubt there are enough [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) questions that truly belong on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) to make the need *common* enough. (I'm not sure how many Database Administrators users would be familiar enough with the on-topic rules for Information Security either).

There might be a case for adding a shortcut for more common target sites that Database Administrators users are familiar with (perhaps [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)), but the current [migration metrics](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) ([moderator tools privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) required) for the past 90 days indicate that only one question was migrated from Database Administrators to Server Fault (total migrations: 69 to SO, 1 to SF, nothing else).

Perhaps we need to get better at flagging for moderator intervention in these types of cases, so the metrics better reflect the reality. It may also be that the reality is that we get very, very few questions that ought to be migrated to a site other than Stack Overflow.

Comment: True enough - I think that this is the first one that I wanted to migrate that wasn't suitable for StackOverflow. I forgot about the flagging option - I'll keep that in mind, thanks. Marking as correct.

Answer (score 15):

I migrated it and the migration was rejected: that's not a bad outcome for a question we aren't sure about, but the response I had [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22301009#22301009) was:

> I'm not sure whether it is an ontopic question or not, but it fails to meet the "being a question" criterion :-)

Which is a bit worrying - we probably only want to migrate those we are reasonably confident actually are questions! If there's any doubt we can just close 'off-topic' here and maybe comment with a suggestion like "try xyz.se but please read their help pages and make the question clearer first"

At the end of the day it isn't our job as a site to make sure every off-topic question find the perfect place on the internet or even on SE to be asked.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a valid question to be considered a valid question on any site. We shouldn't migrate crap to other sites for the same reasons we don't want them migrating crap to us.